# Can't understand Key Error caused by pandas at Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

So here is part of the code with the noted problem. I think that the problem might be caused by pandas update, cause a long time ago everything seemed to work fine. TY

## Read in class scores

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/student-mat.csv')
```

## Filter out grades that were 0

```
df = df[~df['G3'].isin([0, 1])]

df = df.rename(columns={'G3': 'Grade'})

df.head()
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
```

### Log:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda51\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'G3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2948d93a326d> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # Filter out grades that were 0
----> 5 df = df[~df['G3'].isin([0, 1])]
      6 
      7 df = df.rename(columns={'G3': 'Grade'})

~\Anaconda51\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\Anaconda51\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\Anaconda51\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

~\Anaconda51\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

~\Anaconda51\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'G3'
```

Comment: What does `df.head()` show? It looks like there is no column named `G3`.

Comment: omg..
Re-uploaded code to folder, and it works now. Thanks!

But
Sorry for stupid questions, I'm only started studying both python, jupyter notebook, pymc3, pandas, etc..
but
What should I do instead of reuploading source each time after launch to see changes in code?

or .ipynb makes changes to itself so i should keep an original version as a basis?
TY

Answer (score 1):

Second time you execute the notebook, you don't have "G3" anymore, as it's now "Grade".

What you need to do is to make your cells consistent, and not write them so that code inside one cell depends on the state of the previous cell.

For instance in this case, the cell to remove "G3" from the dataset should be a cell on its own, so that you know that afetr this cell, you cannot use G3 anymore.